# Add Index to build Method where alertDialog is in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I need to call the index to recuperate user information into an AlertDialog
The build Method should have index but I dont know how to add.
this is the variable need to call:

```
final Message chat = chats[index];
```

and I need index into build method:

```
class InfluencerDescription extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  InfluencerDescription({this.user});


  @override
  _InfluencerDescriptionState createState() => _InfluencerDescriptionState();
}

class _InfluencerDescriptionState extends State<InfluencerDescription> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context ) {
    return AlertDialog(
      elevation: 20,
      content: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                  elevation: 10,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'AVVIA UNA \n CHAT CON ME',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 13),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => ChatScreen(user: HERE NEED TO CALL CHAT.SENDER VAR,),),);
                  }
              ),
```

Comment: Could you provide more code and description?  I guess you want access user variable inside your state which you can do by using ```widget.user```.

Comment: I f I use only widget.user I get on the next screen.. the error that needs also the "name" of the variable, because I need INDEX into the alert Dialog, in other screen where I have the Index I have the ListView.builder with Index property

Comment: as you can see above my variable: ` final Message chat = chats[index];
    ` has index but It return error because into build Method I dont have it, if I remove index and I put a number 3 for example it return the number 3 user I need to get the index to return the user correctly